# jQuery UI Dialog set Text of Input Box dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've tried figuring this out, but still having some trouble.

I want to set the text (e.g. Name) of an Input Box in a Dialog form from inside the script because the text will be determined at run time. I don't know it at design time. I have learned that the text comes from:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

From the ... label for="name">Name.. to be specific.

The form is actuallyderived from the JQuery UI standard example:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

My questions are:

Can I avoid this way to set the text at all? Can I set it entirely via the script?

If not, how can I change it via the script?

If not, how can I access the text "Name" in the html and change it from the script?

Answer (score 2):

```
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </fieldset>

<script>
var text = $('#name').prev().text(); // get the text

$('#name').prev().text('YourTextHere'); // Change the text
</script>
```